# C#, Visual Studio ASP NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Não sei o que eu fiz com o meu Visual Studio, mas quando vou criar um novo arquivo no ASP NET Core MVC ele não crias os controladores e etc. Alem do Erro que aparece.
Obrigado pela ajuda!
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: O problema é no SDK instalado ou corrompido, dá uma olhada nessa pagina e instale novamente https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download

Comment: Consegui!! Muito obrigado pela ajuda!! Só entrar nesse site e fazer o download do .Net Core SDK compatível ao VS 2017 e ele repara o erro!!!

Comment: Poste como uma resposta para sua pergunta!